# can't seem to install custom libvirt

Tags: ppa, virtualization, pinning

I just can't seem to install a custom version of libvirt on Ubuntu Server 14.04. I'm using [this](https://launchpad.net/~zulcss/+archive/ubuntu/esx) PPA and I used the method of manually pasting in the following lines to the bottom of my **sources.list** file:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/zulcss/esx/ubuntu trusty main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/zulcss/esx/ubuntu trusty main
```

I also created the following **/etc/apt/preferences** file:

```
Package: libvirt-bin
Pin: origin ppa.launchpad.net
Pin-Priority: 610

Package: libvirt-bin
Pin: origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
Pin-Priority: 600

Package: libvirt-bin
Pin: origin security.ubuntu.com
Pin-Priority: 590
```

Here is the output of **apt-cache policy libvirt-bin**

```
libvirt-bin:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.2.2-0ubuntu9
  Package pin: 1.2.2-0ubuntu9
  Version table:
     1.2.2-0ubuntu13.1.14 610
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.2.2-0ubuntu13.1.7 610
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
     1.2.2-0ubuntu13 610
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     1.2.2-0ubuntu9 610
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/zulcss/esx/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

Here is what happens when I actually try and install:

```
root@ubuntu:/etc/apt/sources.list.d# apt-get install libvirt-bin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libvirt-bin : Depends: libvirt0 (= 1.2.2-0ubuntu9) but 1.2.2-0ubuntu13.1.14 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
root@ubuntu:/etc/apt/sources.list.d#
```

Can anyone think of a way of resolving this without manually compiling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign a higher priority to all the packages from the PPA:

```
Package: *
Pin: origin ppa.launchpad.net
Pin-Priority: 610
```

If you assign a priority only for `libvirt-bin`, dependency packages like `libvirt0` aren't affected, so `apt-get` picks the highest available version for those, which would be the one from Ubuntu. The PPA provides these packages:

```
libvirt-bin
libvirt-dev
libvirt-doc
libvirt0
libvirt0-dbg
```

So you could also assign a priority for just `libvirt-bin` and `libvirt0`:

```
Package: libvirt-bin libvirt0
Pin: origin ppa.launchpad.net
Pin-Priority: 610
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a configuration

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/preferences.d/zulcss-esx-ppa-pin
```

with the content

```
Package: *
Pin: release o=LP-PPA-zulcss-esx
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

to favor all packages in this PPA.

I use a similar configuration also for my [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~andreas-boettger/+archive/ubuntu/gmusicbrowser-daily).